# Strings versus controls in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

why can images not be appended to a div in asp?

```
divHtml.append(img);
```

why do I have to use `div.controls.add(img);`?

and why cant I add a string to controls.add say like this

```
div.controls.add(img + String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
```

?
Orginally "In the beginning"

I had this code:

```
    cn.Open();
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Wallpostings FROM WallPosting WHERE UserID=" + theUserId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))

    using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            divHtml.Append("<div id=test>");
            divHtml.Append(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)));
            divHtml.Append("</div>");
        }


        test1.InnerHtml = divHtml.ToString();

    }
}
```

}

Which gave me this out put (notice the css is applied and all spacing etc is nice and neat:

[image]

Then I did this code:

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                //div.ID = "test";
                div.Style["float"] = "left";
                Image img = new Image();
                img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
                img.AlternateText = "Test image";
                div.Controls.Add(img);
                test1.Controls.Add(div);

                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                //div1.ID = "test";
                div1.InnerText = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));

                div1.Style["float"] = "left";
                test1.Controls.Add(div1);

                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                //div2.ID = "test";
                div2.Style["clear"] = "both";
                test1.Controls.Add(div2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And this was my result which is ok but if you notice carefully there is no css between each comment the divs are outside the realm of my css I tryed applying the commented out lines to see if it would work but its just abit funky tbh. Specialy when you look at it in firebug:

[image]
This is what happens if I try parse the control using the method mentioned below:

```
    cn.Open();
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Wallpostings FROM WallPosting WHERE UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
    {
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            test1.Controls.Clear();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");

                div.ID = "test";
                div.Style["float"] = "left";
                Image img = new Image();
                img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
                img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                div.Controls.Add(img);
                div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0))); 

                test1.Controls.Add(div);
```

[image]

Edit:

```
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            test1.Controls.Clear();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.Attributes["class"] = "test";
        div.Style["float"] = "left";

        div.ID = "test";
        //div.Style["float"] = "left";
        Image img = new Image();
        img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
        img.AlternateText = "Test image";

        div.Controls.Add(img);
        div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)))); 

        test1.Controls.Add(div);
```

Shadow managed to get this to work and I used the parse from the other comment aswell.

But problem remains now with test1 div not expanding with test divs:

[image]

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Post Message" Width="98px" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
        </p>
    <p>
    </p>
        <div id="test1" runat="server" />
//could be this line
    </asp:Content>
```

Or it could be

```
test1.Controls.Add(div);
```

in my code thats not being picked up or in the correct brackets maybe?
css:

```
div#test1 
{

}
div .test
{
  width:90%; 
  z-index:1; 
  padding:27.5px; 
  border-top: thin solid #736F6E;
  border-bottom: thin solid #736F6E;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin:0 auto;
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add image plus literal text coming from database.

The proper way is indeed adding controls - `Image` control like you already have and for the text use `Literal` server control:

```
div.Controls.Add(img);
div.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(reader.GetString(0)));
```

Edit: if you insist on getting the HTML string of the image control for your own reasons, it's possible using such code:

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(html))
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        image.RenderControl(textWriter);
    }
}
```

This will render the image into `html` variable, then you can assign the string value to the `Text` of some other control like you originally did. For example:

```
myLabel.Text = html.ToString();
```

Edit II: to apply CSS to the controls you're adding, first change the CSS itself from this: `div#test` to this instead: `div .test`

Now add this single line to your code:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
div.Attributes["class"] = "test";
div.Style["float"] = "left";
...
```

This will apply **class** to each top level `div` and this can be used to apply the proper CSS.

Comment: `Literal` only has a default constructor.

Comment: @Steven thanks, going to fix this now. Meant `LiteralControl`.

Comment: ok hold on shadow im going to re-edit from the beginning to try to explain to everyone whats happening and yourself maybe it might help on the debugging

Comment: ok edit done, im now about to try implement your method shadow, will post back on the results

Comment: hahahahahaha Shadow seriously its scary how much you understand idiots like me, that worked like a charm. But there is one last flaw test1 div isnt being expanded along with test i will upload a new image to show you, i tryed div .test1 to see if that would also work but it doesnt? you will notice in the picture its black in the background and under the textbox and button lies the test1 div

Comment: @Garrith - result of helping hundreds of *newbies* over the last 10 years. :)  This time I couldn't figure what you mean though.. can you add screenshot of desired look of the output or explain it better?

Comment: yeah sorry if you look at the last image the one with the result of you helping me, you will notice behind the images and text its a black background, originaly this was a slight grey (you may have to save the image to your desktop to see it clearly) this is the result of div test1 auto expanding with all the div "test" being inserted into it, test1 is just a container for all the test's but it isnt auto expanding? So im thinking div id =test is being placed outside of div id=test1

Comment: compare my first image to the last image and you will see the test1 div in the background of the first image

Comment: strange firebug does say test divs are all inside test1 div so why isnt the grey area expanding? :S

Comment: @Garrith that's because they're all floating. Do you also add `div` with `style="clear: both;"` like you used to have? Try to add it back.

Comment: tryed adding it just be4 the test1.Controls made no difference?

Comment: ahh I had to remove div style float left works now thanks again shadow

Comment: Cheers @Garrith, assumed you had it for a reason. Thanks for updating us! :)

Comment: hey shadow got a new question again if you could help lol http://stackoverflow.com/users/477228/garrith-graham

Answer (score 4):

`img` is of type `System.Web.UI.Control`, which is the type accepted by `Controls.Add`. In particular, `System.Web.UI.Control` is not the same as `System.String`.

Since C# is a strongly-typed language, a method accepting `System.Web.UI.Control` (like `Add` on `System.Web.UI.ControlCollection`) cannot accept a `System.String` as a parameter.

Similarly, assuming `divHtml` is a `System.StringBuilder`, there is no `Append` method on `System.StringBuilder` taking type `System.Web.UI.Control`, so attempting to pass `img` to the existing `Append` method will fail.

(You may also be having trouble getting your code to compile since you are not using the correct names for your methods and properties; it is `Controls` not `controls`, `Add` not `add`, and `Append` not `append`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want this, you can always create an extension method for this:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void Add(this WebControl control, string html)
    {
        control.Controls.Add(new Literal
        {
            Text = html, Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
div.Controls.Add(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because controls aren't just strings.  They are objects that become strings of html when they actually render.  Do some reading on control and page lifecycle in asp.net webforms.

Answer (score 1):

you can add strings to a control, you will have to use ParseControl() this will convert strings to control, or as controls

```
div.controls.add(ParseControl(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)));
```

Comment: what does this do to the text from the string?

Comment: It just dumps it in the control as string with no alterations.

Comment: yeah Have alook at the edit, this works it does exactly what im after but for some reason I loose all control on the page, the image is to the left like I need and the text is directly attributed to the image all is well but for some reason the css goes haywire.